# Inner join MYSQL query not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, outer-join

I have a table structure with three tables: profiles, profile_subrubriek and rubrieken. I query the data with the following query:

```
SELECT profiles.hoofdrubriek, profiles.plaats
, profiles.bedrijfsnaam, profiles.gemeente, profiles.bedrijfsslogan
, profiles.straatnaam, profiles.huisnummer, profiles.postcode
, profiles.telefoonnummer, profiles.fax, profiles.email
, profiles.website, profiles.bedrijfslogo 

FROM profiles INNER JOIN profile_subrubriek ON profiles.ID=profile_subrubriek.profile_id 
INNER JOIN rubrieken ON profile_subrubriek.subrubriek_id=rubrieken.ID  

where (
rubrieken.rubriek = 'Aannemersbedrijven' 
OR 
profiles.hoofdrubriek = 'Aannemersbedrijven') 
AND profiles.gemeente = 'Dongen'
```

The result, 0 rows. That is not correct. If I take out the Inner Join and only incorporate the 'hoofdrubriek' column in the WHERE clausule I get about 25 rows as a result, that is correct. So this query (modified version of the above) does actually work:

```
SELECT profiles.hoofdrubriek, profiles.plaats, profiles.bedrijfsnaam
, profiles.gemeente, profiles.bedrijfsslogan, profiles.straatnaam
, profiles.huisnummer, profiles.postcode, profiles.telefoonnummer
, profiles.fax, profiles.email, profiles.website, profiles.bedrijfslogo 

FROM profiles where (profiles.hoofdrubriek = 'Aannemersbedrijven') 
AND profiles.gemeente = 'Dongen'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: break your queries/code into multiple lines - they are difficult to read

Comment: i would suggest that you check your data.

Comment: Suggests the data does not have a record to match profiles.hoofdrubriek = 'Aannemersbedrijven' in the other 2 tables. Possibly try using left joins to see what comes back

Comment: Same here. Are you sure that every entry you`d like to retrieve has profile_subrubriek.profile_id and profile_subrubriek.subrubriek_id. In other words, are the join conditions ok for the data you`d like to get?

Comment: Using LEFT JOIN was the answer! Even though I'm not really sure why..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the joined tables don't contain referenced values. Try `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: I would put this as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: The difference is that INNER JOIN will give only result when there are related record in the other table also.

Comment: Slight problem though, when you filter in the where clause with a field from an outer joined table, the join effectively becomes an inner join.  That might be happening with, rubrieken.rubriek = 'Aannemersbedrijven' .  Hard to tell though without seeing the modified query.

Answer (score 1):

Start troubleshooting with this query.

```
select count(*) records
FROM profiles INNER JOIN profile_subrubriek ON profiles.ID=profile_subrubriek.profile_id
```

If records is greater than 1, add this line and run it again:

```
INNER JOIN rubrieken ON profile_subrubriek.subrubriek_id=rubrieken.ID
```

Keep adding bits of your original query, one by one, until records is zero.  The last thing you added will be the reason.