# INNER JOIN SQL Query not working with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have created two tables in my database and normally my php file is able to get table data from mysql.
But when I add INNER JOIN or anything like that, it does not work anymore.  No output is seen but also no error message (so the code have to be correct, I think).

Here's my php code:

```
<?php

$db_name = "mydatabase";
$mysql_username = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$server_name = "localhost";


$conn = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_username,$mysql_password,$db_name);

$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM firsttable INNER JOIN secondtable ON firsttable.secondtable_id = secondtable.secondtable_id");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
      $flag[] = $row;
    }

    print(json_encode($flag));
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: post the schema of both table

Comment: `SELECT * FROM firsttable INNER JOIN secondtable ON firsttable.secondtable_id = secondtable.secondtable_id` Have you tried this query in MySQL Workbench or any other DATABASE IDE?

Comment: Does this query return any data if you run it outside of PHP?

Comment: What happen when you run this in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Seems there are no related data in second table, so query result is empty.

Comment: Is the  `firsttable` id and `secondtable` id are related and has same data type ?

Comment: Please can you post some sample data from both tables

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349626/inner-join-mysql-query-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug like

```
1.if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


 2.$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM firsttable INNER JOIN secondtable ON firsttable.secondtable_id = secondtable.secondtable_id");
    if (!$query) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no error in your program ! Make sure the database connection is established or not

```
if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

The mysql query seems to be correct .. better you post your database structure ! and check the column name

```
firsttable.secondtable_id = secondtable.secondtable_id
```

in your code both are **secondtable_id**, is that correct column name  ?